# Which version KitKat blocks write permission to SD Card?

Tags: java, android, android-4.4-kitkat

I have heard that Android KitKat restrict app's write permission to the SD Card, however, on my Moto X Android KitKat 4.4.4 device, my app still can write(create folder) without any problem.

**I know there are different version of KitKat**

4.4

4.4.1

4.4.2

4.4.3

4.4.4

Thus, I would like to know which version of KitKat restricts an app from writing to SD Card? I would like to inform the user that their Android OS version is not supported for certain functionalities.

thanks, any comments and suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to know which version of KitKat restricts an app from writing to SD Card?

The [tests for blocking write access to removable media](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/android-4.4.2_r2/hostsidetests/appsecurity/test-apps/WriteExternalStorageApp) in the Compatibility Test Suite were added in the Android 4.4 edition of the Suite, according to [Dave Smith](http://www.doubleencore.com/2014/03/android-external-storage/). Hence, devices that ship with Android 4.4+ should not allow write access, but devices upgraded to 4.4 from earlier versions of Android may retain write access.

However, as JoaoBiriba points out, this is for [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). The Moto X appears to lack a removable media card slot. You may be testing with [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), which is something else entirely and may have nothing to do with an an "SD Card".

Answer (score 1):

Moto X has not SD-Card, only internal storage so this is not blocked

```
http://lifehacker.com/android-kitkat-blocks-some-access-to-micro-sd-cards-1524997895
```